# Nest1.0: ConnectionStatus error handling

Tags: nest

I have a question regarding to Nest1.0pr and the connection error handling. In the previous versions of Nest I was using IResponse.ConnectionStatus.Error. It seems to me that the property Error does not exist in the new version anymore. However in the documentation I found the following:

> ConnectionStatus is the response as it was returned by
>   Elasticsearch.net. It's section on handling responses applies here as
>   well.

And in the very section the property Error is mentioned.

> Error When a call succeeds but does not return a http status code of
>   200 this property will have details on the error. Read more about
>   error handling here

So is the recommended way to check whether the property Success is false?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changed when NEST was refactored to use Elasticsearch.Net.  Now when a request fails, you can try checking the `IResponse.ConnectionStatus.OriginalException` property, which will contain the actual Elasticsearch error.